# Short film in stop-motion with cabbages living in a dystopian city

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, short-film

It was a short movie that I saw in a movie theater before the main movie (can't remember the movie). I saw it in Belgium, but there was no intelligible dialogue in it. I *think* I saw this between 2000 and 2012.

It's basically an adaptation of 1984, with cabbages moving in stop-motion. They live in a white (or grey?) city, probably in paper. I clearly remember a little bridge.

All of the cabbages are red. There's a picture of the leader everywhere, and he gives speeches in a gibberish language. Every red cabbage seems to act like a soldier.

The hero is a green cabbage, who is clearly different and thinks differently. He's presented as a dreamer, I guess.  He hides himself from the other military red cabbages. I think he also speaks to other cabbages in secret reunions, maybe to start a revolution.

The hero is finally captured by the red cabbages. I can't remember the process but he finally turns red too (like he was brainwashed). It's quite tragic.

The camera leaves the city but we have a last hope; another green cabbage can be seen moving on the screen, with the same music used to introduce the first green cabbage.

Comment: Do you remember which theater you saw it at?

Comment: Should this be closed under our talking vegetables policy? ;)

Comment: @ DonFusili: Yes, I know the place. It's a little theater in Bastogne (Belgium). If I have no results here, I'll probably ask the owner of the place the next time I'll go there (he sells the tickets and he's very sympathetic. I hope he has a good memory)

Comment: Could it be that you mixed some things up and it is Zero? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOMbySJTKpg

Comment: @kl78: No, it's not Zero. I clearly remember cabbages (or sprouts ? I was not an vegetable-expert at this time).

Comment: The description sounds very familiar. I wonder if this a "stand alone" short movie or more like the intro of full movie. Do you remember how long this movie was(only 1-2 minutes or more like 10 minutes)?

Comment: It was not brief. Something like 5 or 10 minutes